# Split string on backslash or forward slash

Tags: javascript, regex, split

Given the following test cases:

1. `res/js/test`
2. `res\js\test`
3. `res/js\test`
4. `res\js/test`

**How can I split a string by either forward slash or backslash?** My attempt works when the string is only backslashes(test case 1) but doesn't work for forward slashes or a mixture of both (test cases 2, 3, 4).

```
test.split(/[\\\/]/);
```

[Here's my fiddled attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx1xny35/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your string does not contain any backslashes, but esaped `\j`, and `\t` wich is the value for tab.
Your Code is correct, but your input is not, use this:

```
var test = [
    'res/js/test',
    'res\\js\\test',
    'res/js\\test',
    'res\\js/test'
    ];
```

Only a escaped backslash will make a backslash in a string `'\\'`

Answer (score 6):

This is what I ended up doing.

I replaced all backslashes with forward slashes before splitting by forward slash.

```
test.replace(/\\/g, '/').split('/');
```